# Django invoice model formset

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-templates, formset

I am trying to create an invoice form. I am trying to use a formset because the products will be added more than once in the sales process. I am constantly failing in form creation.

My Models:

```
class Fatura(models.Model):
musteri = models.ForeignKey(CariModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
fatura_tarihi = models.DateField(auto_now=True, blank=False)
fatura_numarasi = models.CharField(max_length=36, default=fatura_numarasi)
odeme_tarihi = models.DateField(auto_now=False, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return "{} - {}".format(self.musteri, self.fatura_numarasi)

class FaturaUrunler(models.Model):
fatura = models.ForeignKey(Fatura, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
baslik = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False)
urun = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False)
miktar = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=3, default=1)
fiyat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=3)
vergi = models.CharField(choices=KDV, default=18, max_length=5)
```

My Views:

```
def index(request):

class GerekliFormlar(BaseFormSet):
    def __int__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GerekliFormlar,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = Fatura.object.none()

UrunlerFormset = formset_factory(UrunForm, max_num=0, formset=GerekliFormlar)

if request.method == 'POST':
    fatura_form = FaturaForm(request.POST)
    urunler_formset = UrunlerFormset(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if fatura_form.is_valid() and urunler_formset.is_valid():
        fatura = fatura_form.save()
        for form in urunler_formset.forms:
            urunler = form.save()
            urunler.fatura = fatura
            urunler.save()
        return HttpResponse("tesekkürler")
else:
    fatura_form = FaturaForm()
    urunler_formset = UrunForm()

c = {
    'fatura_form': fatura_form,
    'urunler_formset': urunler_formset
}
c.update(csrf(request))

return render_to_response('anasayfa_gecici.html', c)
```

I would like to make customer selection and product addition within the form. Simple billing system

Comment: You have `urunler_formset = UrunForm()` - don't you want to instantiate a formset instead?

Comment: Also, note that `render_to_response` is obsolete. Use `return render(request, 'anasayfa_gecici.html', c)` instead, and then you can remove the `c.update(csrf(request))` line.

Comment: @Alasdair "return render (request, 'homepage_gecici.html', c)" this solved the problem.  thanks you very much for your help.

Comment: Switching to `render` is a good change, but that won't have fixed the problem of setting `urunler_formset = UrunForm()`,

Answer (score 0):

In your view you were instantiating a form `UrunForm()` for GET requests and a formset `UrunlerFormset()` for POST requests. You should use a `UrunlerFormset` in both cases.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    fatura_form = FaturaForm(request.POST)
    urunler_formset = UrunlerFormset(request.POST, request.FILES)
    ...    
else:
    fatura_form = FaturaForm()
    urunler_formset = UrunlerFormset()
```